# Why do I have to double-encode javascript a href links?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
 <a href="http://localhost/test.html?x=%c2%ae">Test1</a>
 <a href="javascript:window.location='http://localhost/test.html?x=%c2%ae'">Test2</a>
 <a href="javascript:window.location='http://localhost/test.html?x=%25c2%25ae'">Test3</a>
</html>
```

(%c2%ae is ® in url-encoded UTF-8)

Use a tool like fiddler, you can't rely on the browser location bar. Test1 and Test3 call the same URL, Test2 something different (and different between browsers).

What's the reason for this behaviour, why do I have to double-encode the javascript href?

Comment: Why would you not just set href to begin with?

Comment: `javascript:window.location=` Uh, why???

Comment: Yes why do you have to double encode href when you can just use a URL directly?

Comment: That's obviously not real code but the smallest example to reproduce the behaviour. The real code was something like javascript:someFunction('parameter') -someFunction did a window.open with the parameter later on- which behaved (with special characters) not as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Worth noting that this is a pretty bad practice and you should just use

```
href="http://localhost/test.html?x=%C2%AE"
```

As you did with Test1.

---

The reason you need to doubly escape is because the browser will unescape the input once for the `href=""` attribute, and once more for the `window.location=` change.